# Entity Framework - Key component 'Id' not a declared property on type

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, database-design

Working with entity framework 6.2, targeting framework 4.6.1.
I got this base class :

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    [NotMapped]
    public virtual ulong Id { get; set; }
    internal virtual long ID
    {
        get
        {unchecked{return (long)Id;}}
        set
        {unchecked{Id = (ulong)value;}}
    }
}
```

And class that extands the base class

```
    public class AccountingTransaction : Entity
    {
      //other propeties
    }
```

My configuration looks like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Types<AccountingTransaction>().Configure(c => c.Ignore(x => x.Id));
    modelBuilder.Entity<AccountingTransaction>()
                    .Property(x => x.ID)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnName("ID");

    modelBuilder.Entity<AccountingTransaction>()
                    .HasKey(x => x.ID);
}
```

When trying to initialize the db I get an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException   Message=The key component 'ID' is
>   not a declared property on type 'AccountingTransaction'. Verify that
>   it has not been explicitly excluded from the model and that it is a
>   valid primitive property.

I support mulitply frameworks (.net standard 2.0 and .net 4.6.1) similar code configurated on .net standard works, running this code on .net 4.6.1 project fails.

Do I have to specify the ID on each entity seperetly? It would be annoying because of the mapping from ulong and the readablity of the this would be horrible. Please if someone will answer use fluentApi.

//EDIT
It works if I move the Id from Entity class to AccountingTransaction. But I'm looking for some other configuration option.

Comment: btw if possible rate my question up if it's not that stupid since if not I won't be able to post anything on stack and now I hardly ever do it :(

Comment: Maybe you should explain why `Id` has to be `ulong`. If it would just be `long` *and* mapped you wouldn't have to add any mapping code for this property.

Comment: Well it's something we get from external API and architect decided that Id has to be ulong, so I have to keep the mapping here. Seems like it's just a business requirement. I know it's problematic :P That's why I ask it here.

Comment: Is that totally non-negotiable? They probably want to ensure that non-negative Ids are stored in the database, but if the database columns have identity specifications this is practically guaranteed. Anyway, you can get it working by making the property public (and, if you like, the setter protected).